# How can I add multiple modems to windows XP when only one physical modem is connected?

Tags: windows-xp, modem

I'm working with some older software (Procomm Plus) and it requires about 40 modems to be installed. It doesn't need 40 physical modems installed, just around 40 installed in windows xp and mapped to a different com port.

After I get the fist modem (US Robotics 5686) installed it is attached to COM1. My next step would be going back to "Phone and Modem Options" selecting "Add..." and then re-add the same modem again but attaching to a new COM port.

The problem is that I don't get an option to install the UR modem (doesn't show up in manufactures) and if I click on have disk and select the inf file nothing shows up there either...even though I just used this inf to install the first modem.

There are still some workstations that have this installed and working but it has been a few years since this was done and no on remembers how it was done.

Any ideas on this?

Note: this is for a corporate imaging project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: The problem ended up being the driver version I was using. I found a driver that was older and at that point I was able to install more modems.